# How to create a custom multi-progress bar in Qt

Tags: qt

I am working on a multi -segment download manager. I want to display the segmentation procedure. QGraphicsScene works fine but , unfortunately it slows the download. Is there any better option, other than using QProgressBars.
  I am using QNetworkAccessManager to download files. If I connect the downloadProgress signal of QNetworkManager object to a slot of Main Gui Thread which draws on QGraphicsView, the download speed decreases even upto 10 times in some cases

```
    // a custom progress bar
void Download::showGProgress(int num, float prgrss)                                 //slot
{
    prgrss=prgrss/100;
    x_coord=(ui->graphicsView_2->width()-3)*prgrss;                              
    for(float b=0;b<=x_coord;b=b+0.5)
    {
        progress.addRect(0,0,x_coord,y_coord);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why does QGraphicsScene slow the download? I am not sure I understand why you are encountering performance issues.

Comment: I tested it many times and there was a considerable change in download speed everytime. I don't know why, perhaps drawing on QGraphicsScene is a costly process

Comment: I get the feeling that your performance issues are related to how you are performing the download vs the drawing. Are you downloading via the main thread or is it in another thread?

Comment: QNetworAccessManager runs in a separate thread by default. Anyways it is a multi-threaded application. Actually signals sent from download thread, draw in the gui thread, perhaps drawing is much slower

Comment: From this code example...Does it just draw rectangles over itself constantly? And setting the scene over and over when it doesn't need to? I really feel like this has to be your over all design and not something inherent to graphics scene or QProgressBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QNetworkAccessManager` is not threaded. It is asynchronous, using the current threads eventloop. It is the HTTP requests which it create that are the threaded aspect.

This would explain why anything you do in your main thread could theoretically slow down the operations of the download. Though not necessarily the underlying threaded download itself, but rather the signaling response time that would allow you to have fast feedback about it.

What you should probably do is create your own QThread subclass, and create the `QNetworkAccessManager` in the run() method. And then create a [`QEventLoop`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html) in the thread and call `exec()`

In a nutshell, you need to create your own Threaded QNetworkAccessManager.

Comment: I did that as my initial design. It worked fine but had an issue later causing crashes. I got my code checked by an Qt-Certified expert, in Qt-forum and he told me not to use QThreads with QNetworkAccessManager. My code has more than 4000 lines now and its not possible to revert. As per him Qt 4.8.1 runs QNetworkAccessManager in a separate thread, and i feel its true as it doesnt interfere with gui thread at all

Comment: From what I see, it is the http requests that are run in threads. Not the entire network manager. That is the only explanation for why signals would slow down your network manager. Because they are sharing the same event loop. If the manager were completely threaded, then nothing would slow down your downloads.

Comment: Using timer to update scene after every second instead of signals, resolves the problem. But resizing the window renders the scene useless. I need to override the resize event and redraw the scene as per new width.

Answer (score 1):

create your own widget to do what you would like

this is easier than it sounds.

Make a class that subclasses from a QWidget. And in this widget make a Horizontal Sizer that contains 100 Qlabels (store the QLabels in a vector). Give it slots to 'update' the current progress by setting the background color of each QLabel to a different color. This should be fairly easy to do progressively, meaning you store the current 'percentage' as a member variable and then only adjust the fields that are necessary to get to the percentage that you're looking for (This will eliminate some flickering if you were to do it from scratch every time).

Add functions that will switch the sizer to a vertical one instead of a horizontal one to make it even more customizable.

This allows you to get creative in the what you can do for the progress bar as each element could be a different picture, or a different color, or whatever you would like.

Comment: Its a good idea, but it seems to lack smoothness. I mean if the download is divided into 16 segments, all the 16 parts should atleast appear moving. Lot of space complexity too.

Comment: I wouldn't even use a bunch of QLables with background colors. I would just use a custom paint event that draws a rectangle of a certain widget of the total widget. much faster. Only one thing to draw once per update.

Comment: I did something exactly similar on QGraphicsScene, but it slows the download speed!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try QProgressBar? Maybe you can write a subclass of it to handle your own properties.

Comment: I tried but it has some issues. Suppose two downloads are running one having 4 segments and the other having six segments. selecting the downloads should change the number of progress bars dynamically being displayed on a widget. from 4 to six, six to 4. And transition is not so smooth anyways